# Windows command line - pipe output of dir search to (truncate) operation

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, pipe

This is Windows 10.  The question is very simple, I simply don't know the proper syntax to do this.

This will list all files ending in .log:

```
dir /s /p *.log
```

This will truncate a file:

```
echo|set /p=>"myfile.log"
```

What I would like to do is pipe the output of the first operation to the second operation, thus truncating the matching files returned by `dir`.  How would I do this?

Comment: So you want to clear every log in a directory of any input it could have?

Comment: Yes Seth that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Piping for the normal cmd isn't that common in Windows. So for the cmd you'd probably have to get a list of those files in variable and use a for loop to process them. Maybe you could also directly use the `dir` command in the loop.

I'd opt for PowerShell, which does a similar thing but is way more readable in my opinion:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.log" | Clear-Content
```

If you want to confirm every single file (the `/P` on your `dir` does pause every screen) you could use the `-Confirm` switch on `Clear-Content`.

If you'd want to use a for loop for whatever reason and use echo you could use:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "*.log" | %{ echo $null > $_; }
```

Comment: I will look into PowerShell.  Perhaps a link to that for future viewers of this post.  Thanks.

Comment: I tried this and added -Recurse succesfully, and -Filter exactfilename.log successfully, however, PowerShell doesn't seem to like the * character

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't like the asterisk? Did you put it in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

To just collect the dir output in the log file, drop the /p and redirect
dir /s *.log >myfile.log

That will create a new file, deleting any previous contents.

If you want the full path on each line, instead of listing by subdirectory, use /b
dir /s /b *.log >myfile.log

Comment: Leo, that is not what i want to do.  i want to truncate the files the `dir` returns to 0 bytes - not write anything to myfile.log.  There is no myfile.log - that is just an example.  Edited my post to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I truncate the matching files returned by `dir /s /p *.log`?

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /s *.log') do (
  echo|set /p=>"%%f"
  )
endlocal
```

Example usage:

```
> dir /s /p *.log
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test

02/10/2016  17:02             2,305 test.log
               1 File(s)          2,305 bytes

 Directory of F:\test\test

02/10/2016  17:02             2,305 test.log
               1 File(s)          2,305 bytes

 Directory of F:\test\test with space

02/10/2016  17:02             2,305 test.log
               1 File(s)          2,305 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               3 File(s)          6,915 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,737,619,595,264 bytes free

> test

> dir /s /p *.log
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of F:\test

24/11/2016  10:39                 0 test.log
               1 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of F:\test\test

24/11/2016  10:39                 0 test.log
               1 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of F:\test\test with space

24/11/2016  10:39                 0 test.log
               1 File(s)              0 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               3 File(s)              0 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,737,619,607,552 bytes free
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.